# pandas drop_duplicates behavior in a multiindex

Tags: python, debugging, pandas

I am observing some interesting behavior in the `drop_duplicates` function. It tends to remove more rows than it maybe should be. See the below example where the method deletes NON-DUPLICATE entry via the datadf but keeps it via a smaller dataframe:

```
testdf = datadf.loc['2013-09']

In[228]: datadf.drop_duplicates().loc['2013-09-04']
Out[228]: 
id        RXZ13
close    137.75
Name: 2013-09-04 00:00:00, dtype: object

In[229]: testdf.drop_duplicates().loc['2013-09-04']
Out[229]: 
            id close 
date
2013-09-04 RXU13 139.73
2013-09-04 RXZ13 137.75
```

`datadf.describe` shows 8762 counts, whereas `testdf.describe` shows just 28 counts.

Comment: worth adding that the index is a datetimeindex which is NON-UNIQUE.